# Metal normal doesn't interpolate

Tags: macos, shader, interpolation, metal

I've been learning how Metal works using Swift and targeting macOS. Thing's have been going okay, but now, close to getting the stuff done, I've hit a problem that I cannot possibly understand ... I hope you guys will help me :)

I'm loading and displaying a OBJ teapot, which I'm lighting using ambiant+diffuse+specular light. Lighting in itself works well, but problem is : the normal vector is not interpolated when going to the fragment shader, which results in having flat lighting on supposedly curved surface ... Not good ...

I really don't understand why the normal is not interpolated while other values (position + eye) are ... Here is my shader and an image to show the result :

Thanks in advance :)

```
struct Vertex
{
    float4 position;
    float4 normal;
};

struct ProjectedVertex
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float3 eye;
    float3 normal;
};

vertex ProjectedVertex vertex_project(device Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]],
                                      constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                                      uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    ProjectedVertex outVert;
    outVert.position = uniforms.modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertices[vid].position;
    outVert.eye =  -(uniforms.modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertices[vid].position).xyz;
    outVert.normal = (uniforms.modelViewProjectionMatrix * float4(vertices[vid].normal)).xyz;

    return outVert;
}

fragment float4 fragment_light(ProjectedVertex vert [[stage_in]],
                               constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(0)]])
{
    float3 ambientTerm = light.ambientColor * material.ambientColor;

    float3 normal = normalize(vert.normal);
    float diffuseIntensity = saturate(dot(normal, light.direction));
    float3 diffuseTerm = light.diffuseColor * material.diffuseColor * diffuseIntensity;

    float3 specularTerm(0);
    if (diffuseIntensity > 0)
    {
        float3 eyeDirection = normalize(vert.eye);
        float3 halfway = normalize(light.direction + eyeDirection);
        float specularFactor = pow(saturate(dot(normal, halfway)), material.specularPower);
        specularTerm = light.specularColor * material.specularColor * specularFactor;
    }

    return float4(ambientTerm + diffuseTerm + specularTerm, 1);
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIXVg.png)

Comment: It depends somewhat on what the data looks like. How are the normals computed? If the vertices are duplicated rather than shared, I'd expect this kind of appearance (since the normals will be constant across each face).

Comment: Actually, problem was that I generated normals in the OBJ loader according to normals of each triangle, which lead to each vertex having the same normal and I did not have the normal shared between adjacent triangles. The thing that is weird is that the same code does work using Obj-C so I don't know why I don't get the same result ... I will try to monitor each normal for both and try to understand why, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem was that using OBJ-C, when I indexed the vertices from the OBJ file, I only generated 1 vertex for shared vertices between surfaces, so I kept only 1 normal.

When translating it to swift, the hash value I used to check if the vertex is at the same place than one I already have was wrong and couldn't detect shared vertices, which resulted in keeping all of the normals, so each surface is flat.

I don't know if I'm clear enough but that's what happened, for future reference, this question was about making a Swift version of "metalbyexample" book which is Obj-C only.